# Function which returns type runs multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my first question here so sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

I have a function in PostgreSQL which returns a type and I want to display all fields from that type.
At first I was doing the following SQL:

```
SELECT (FC_FUNCTION(FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C)).*
FROM   TABLE
```

But I noticed that it was running way too slow. After checking it looked like it was running the function again for each field the type had. Changing the SQL to the following not only returned the same results, but was way faster:

```
SELECT (X).*
FROM (SELECT FC_FUNCTION(FIELD_A, FIELD_B, FIELD_C) AS X FROM TABLE) A
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? It feels to me more of a work around than a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the function definition?  And an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE):

> [...] these two queries have the same result:
>
> ```
> SELECT (myfunc(x)).* FROM some_table;
> SELECT (myfunc(x)).a, (myfunc(x)).b, (myfunc(x)).c FROM some_table;
> ```
>
> Tip
>
> PostgreSQL handles column expansion by actually transforming the first form into the second. So, in this example, `myfunc()` would get invoked three times per row with either syntax. If it's an expensive function you may wish to avoid that, which you can do with a query like:
>
> ```
> SELECT m.* FROM some_table, LATERAL myfunc(x) AS m;
> ```
>
> Placing the function in a `LATERAL FROM` item keeps it from being invoked more than once per row. `m.*` is still expanded into `m.a, m.b, m.c`, but now those variables are just references to the output of the `FROM` item. (The `LATERAL` keyword is optional here, but we show it to clarify that the function is getting `x` from `some_table`.)

Comment: I searched and didn't find this documentation, thank you so much!